# paypal ipn issue after payment showing in payment review in magento

Tags: paypal, sandbox, payment

I am facing problem in checkout via paypal sandbox in my store here supplementasia.zylone.com
I have set auto return in paypal account and auto return also and valid ipn return url.
I have set payment review off in paypal developer account still it shows payment status in review not completed...how to fix this?

Comment: Did you disable Payment Review on the Seller or Buyer account? The payment receiving the payment (Seller) would need to have that option disable. Are you processing transactions as a Sale or Authorization?

Comment: Yes I have disabled payment review from seller account.and processing transaction as a Sale.  Payment status is showing processing..Why not complete? any clue? or any other setting required?

Comment: Can you provide a transaction ID of a payment that hasn't completed? Did you turn off payment review before or after the payment occurred?